# Selenium WebDriver document.getElementById instead of send_keys

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I have the following code

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Element_ID").send_keys(str(sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value))
```

Values is taken from excel, but instead `send_keys`, I want to use `document.getElementsByName` script.

How can I adapt the `getElementsByName` script for my situation?

Answer (score 0):

The Python WebDriver API has a method for getting elements by name:

```
find_element_by_name(name)
```

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_name

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you could adapt the `getElementsByName` method to set the value of an input field based on a value from an Excel sheet using Selenium WebDriver with Java:

```
// get the input element by name
List<WebElement> inputElements = driver.findElements(By.name("Element_Name"));

// loop through the input elements to find the one you want
for (WebElement element : inputElements) {
    if (element.getAttribute("id").equals("Element_ID")) {
        // set the value of the input element
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value + "';", element);
        break;
    }
}
```

In the above sample, we first find all the input elements on the page with a particular name using `driver.findElements(By.name("Element_Name"))`. Then, we loop through the input elements to find the one with the correct ID using `element.getAttribute("id").equals("Element_ID")`. Once we've found the correct input element, we use `JavascriptExecutor` to execute a JavaScript command that sets the value of the input element to the value from the Excel sheet using `js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + sheet.cell(row=r, column=2).value + "';", element);`.

In this approach we use JavaScript to set the value of the input field, rather than using the `send_keys` method directly.

You can use this code as reference and write something similar in Python.